# Como usar o sys.arg para entrada de dados

Tags: python

Tenho a função da seguinte maneira:

```
def minha_funcao(x, y )

my code 
. 
.
.
end of my code

e a a entrada de dados eu utlizo da seginte maneira

print my_func([uma lista], [outra lista])
```

Gostaria de usar o `sys.arg` para a pessoa entrar com os dados. E aproveitando, é esta a melhor forma de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Na realidade depende do que queres. Se é a melhor maneira ou não terias de colocar mais código. imagina que executas o código assim `$ python tests.py arg1 arg2` Para usar `argv` podes:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) <= 2: # aqui fazes a verificacao sobre quantos args queres receber, o nome do programa conta como 1
    print('argumentos insuficientes')
    sys.exit()

x = sys.argv[1] # arg1
y = sys.argv[2] # arg2
```

Nota que os `argv` sºao interpretados como string, para converter em lista podes: Suponhamos que excutas o código assim: `$ python3 tests.py 1,2,3 4,5,6`. Sem espaços entre os caracteres de cada um dos argumentos (1,2,3 e 4,5,6): fazes:

```
import sys

def my_func(x, y):
    print(x)
    print(y)

if len(sys.argv) <= 2: # aqui fazes a verificacao sobre quantos args queres receber, o nome do programa conta como 1
    print('argumentos insuficientes')
    sys.exit()

x = sys.argv[1].split(',')
y = sys.argv[2].split(',')

my_func(x,y)
```

Output:

> ['1', '2', '3']
>   ['4', '5', '6']

Sendo que x é a primeira lista e y será a segunda

Para ficar mais perceptível podes enviar `argvs`  mesmo com o formato lista, acho que é isso que queres:

`$ python3 tests.py [1,2,3] [4,5,6]` e fazes:

```
import sys

def my_func(x, y):
    print(x)
    print(y)

if len(sys.argv) <= 2: # aqui fazes a verificacao sobre quantos args queres receber, o nome do programa conta como 1
    print('argumentos insuficientes')
    sys.exit()

x = [i.replace('[', '').replace(']', '') for i in sys.argv[1].split(',')]
y = [i.replace('[', '').replace(']', '') for i in sys.argv[2].split(',')]

my_func(x,y)
```

O output será igual ao exemplo de cima

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do colega Miguel já te dá o caminho e é a solução mais simples, direta e imediata (eu até sugiro que seja a resposta aceita). Mas vale lembrar que existe também o pacote [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) que é muito bom e te permite construir soluções bem profissionais para lidar com o processamento dos argumentos recebidos via linha de comando.

Um exemplo de código que te permite tratar e receber duas listas (só para ilustrar, uma de valores inteiros e outra de valores reais) é esse:

```
import sys
import argparse

# ---------------------------------------------
def main(args):
    """
    Função de entrada.

    Parâmetros
    ----------
    args: lista de str
        Argumentos recebidos da linha de comando.

    Retornos
    --------
    exitCode: int
        Código de erro/sucesso para indicação no término do programa.
    """

    # Processa a linha de comando
    args = parseCommandLine(args)

    # Usa a linha de comando! :)
    print('Valores de Uma Lista:')
    for v in args.umalista:
        print(v)

    print('\nValores de Outra Lista:')
    for v in args.outralista:
        print('{:.2f}'.format(v))

    return 0

# ---------------------------------------------    
def parseCommandLine(args):
    """
    Parseia os argumentos recebidos da linha de comando.

    Parâmetros
    ----------
    args: lista de str
        Argumentos recebidos da linha de comando.

    Retornos
    --------
    args: objeto
        Objeto com os argumentos devidamente processados acessíveis em 
        atributos. Para mais detalhes, vide a documentação do pacote argparse. 
    """

    desc = 'Programa de teste para o SOPT, que ilustra a utilização do pacote '\
           'argparse (para o processamento facilitado de argumentos da linha '\
           'de comando).'
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc)

    hlp = 'Uma lista de valores inteiros. Deve ter no mínimo dois valores.'
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--umalista', nargs='+', type=int, help=hlp)

    hlp = 'Uma lista de valores reais. Deve ter no mínimo um valor.'
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--outralista', nargs='+', type=float, help=hlp)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.umalista is None or len(args.umalista) < 2:
        parser.error('A opção -u/--umalista requer no mínimo 2 valores.')

    if args.outralista is None or len(args.outralista) < 1:
        parser.error('A opção -o/--outralista requer no mínimo 1 valor.')

    return args

# ---------------------------------------------    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Dessa forma, ao executar o programa sem nada, você tem algo assim:

```
C:\temp\SOPT>testeSOPT
usage: testeSOPT.py [-h] [-u UMALISTA [UMALISTA ...]]
                    [-o OUTRALISTA [OUTRALISTA ...]]
testeSOPT.py: error: A opção -u/--umalista requer no mínimo 2 valores.
```

A ajuda (ao executar com o parâmetro -h) é:

```
C:\temp\SOPT>testeSOPT -h
usage: testeSOPT.py [-h] [-u UMALISTA [UMALISTA ...]]
                    [-o OUTRALISTA [OUTRALISTA ...]]

Programa de teste para o SOPT, que ilustra a utilização do pacote argparse
(para o processamento facilitado de argumentos da linha de comando).

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -u UMALISTA [UMALISTA ...], --umalista UMALISTA [UMALISTA ...]
                        Uma lista de valores inteiros. Deve ter no mínimo dois
                        valores.
  -o OUTRALISTA [OUTRALISTA ...], --outralista OUTRALISTA [OUTRALISTA ...]
                        Uma lista de valores reais. Deve ter no mínimo um
                        valor.
```

Se não fornecer itens suficientes para uma das listas, tem algo do tipo:

```
C:\temp\SOPT>testeSOPT -u 2 4
usage: testeSOPT.py [-h] [-u UMALISTA [UMALISTA ...]]
                    [-o OUTRALISTA [OUTRALISTA ...]]
testeSOPT.py: error: A opção -o/--outralista requer no mínimo 1 valor.
```

E, fornecendo a quantidade de valores esperada, você tem:

```
C:\temp\SOPT>testeSOPT -u 2 4 -o 1.45 1.77 2.74 7 23
Valores de Uma Lista:
2
4

Valores de Outra Lista:
1.45
1.77
2.74
7.00
23.00
```

> P.S.: Para evitar que ele use `UMALISTA` maísculo como exemplo de dado
>   de entrada na ajuda, use o atributo [`metavar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar):
>
> ```
> . . .
> hlp = 'Uma lista de valores inteiros. Deve ter no mínimo dois valores.'
> parser.add_argument('-u', '--umalista', nargs='+', type=int, metavar='<número inteiro>', help=hlp)
>
> hlp = 'Uma lista de valores reais. Deve ter no mínimo um valor.'
> parser.add_argument('-o', '--outralista', nargs='+', metavar='<número real>', type=float, help=hlp)
> . . .
> ```
>
> Produz:
>
> ```
> C:\temp\SOPT>testeSOPT -h
> usage: testeSOPT.py [-h] [-u <número inteiro> [<número inteiro> ...]]
>                     [-o <número real> [<número real> ...]]
>
> Programa de teste para o SOPT, que ilustra a utilização do pacote argparse
> (para o processamento facilitado de argumentos da linha de comando).
>
> optional arguments:
>   -h, --help            show this help message and exit
>   -u <número inteiro> [<número inteiro> ...], --umalista <número inteiro> [<número inteiro> ...]
>                         Uma lista de valores inteiros. Deve ter no mínimo dois
>                         valores.
>   -o <número real> [<número real> ...], --outralista <número real> [<número real> ...]
>                         Uma lista de valores reais. Deve ter no mínimo um
>                         valor.
> ```

Comment: É verdade Luiz esse também é uma boa solução, para coisas sérias usaria isso

Comment: Exato, @Miguel. Para coisas rápidas e simples, a sua solução é a melhor (e a sua resposta deveria ser aceita). :)